# How To Get A Pop Up Layout?

Tags: android, layout, popup

How can I have a pop-up window, with a new layout, but with the old layout in the background?

Also I'd like to have a button on the first layout call the second layout based on an if-statement, using something like this

```
"if Button has a background, button open new layout, if not null"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to create the pop-up. For example, in your activity onCreate() method set up a new dialog and specify the layout using XML like normal.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.--);
```

then simply call `dialog.show()` when you want to show the pop-up.